# How to Send iOS push notification to PFUsers

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform, cloud, apple-push-notifications

I am using Parse.com as a backend for my iOS app. And in this app users can favorite items. Which is then saved to Parse. I want to write some script, that will check what users have favorited a certain item, and if they have favorited a certain item to send them a push notification. And I would need this to run everyday. And I am wondering what language or type of code would be best for this. If I should use cloud code, or parse says they have a Javascript SDK.

I am new to use push notifications, so I apologize if this does not make much sense.

Thanks a bunch for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all, to enable Push notifications for your app, you're going to have to follow these steps: 
https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

This tutorial gets you all set up with parse push notifications in your app, but that doesn't answer your question. To answer your question, you probably want a cloud code script that runs every day and creates a PFQuery based on your stored items that you have, and based on if a user has favorited an item create a PFPush instance for that User's installation. You can then create a directed push to that user. I have personally never used Cloud code for push (only client side), but this should work. Since Cloud Code is just javascript, you can create a scheduling type event in cloud code and run your push from there.

Comment: Okay so for that I will install the parse cloud code manager, and then I don't need a server to run this correct, it is all run on parses end. Correct?

Comment: Parse will act as your server, correct.